# How to select rows from a table multiply by n?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, union

I have a select station as below which returns 2 rows:

```
select ID, Title from TableName
```

(The actual query is quite large and returns much more rows but for simplicity assume the above.)

I'd need a query which returns more data and I can't change the database table.

How to multiply/duplicate and increase the number of rows which are returned by e.g. 5 times so that 10 rows are returned instead?

I know with UNION ALL it's possible if I write it 5 times:

```
select ID, Title from TableName
UNION ALL
select ID, Title from TableName
UNION ALL
select ID, Title from TableName
UNION ALL
select ID, Title from TableName
UNION ALL
select ID, Title from TableName
```

But is there any other simpler way? My actual query is much larger and so can't use UNION ALL.

I hope the questions is clear.

Comment: Why do you need your rows to be returned 5 times each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @i INT;

SET @i = 1000;

;WITH n AS (SELECT TOP (@i) object_id FROM sys.all_columns)
SELECT t.ID, t.Title FROM TableName AS t CROSS JOIN n;
```

If you find that the CTE does not provide enough rows, you can always make more!

```
DECLARE @i INT;

SET @i = 1000000;

;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (@i) c.object_id FROM sys.all_columns AS c
   CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS o
)
SELECT t.ID, t.Title FROM TableName AS t CROSS JOIN n;
```

...or you could create your own Numbers table:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @UpperLimit INT = 1000000; -- customize this

;WITH n AS
(
    SELECT
        x = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM       sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s3
)
SELECT Number = x
  INTO dbo.Numbers
  FROM n
  WHERE x BETWEEN 1 AND @UpperLimit;

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(Number)
  -- if Enterprise Edition:
  -- WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
;
```

Now your query can be:

```
DECLARE @i INT;

SET @i = 1000000;

;WITH n AS (SELECT TOP (@i) Number FROM dbo.Numbers)
SELECT t.ID, t.Title FROM TableName AS t CROSS JOIN n;
```